# Something is running on 127.0.0.1, can't open laravel's valet website

Tags: laravel, localhost, laravel-valet

I'm messing up with django/wordpress/node, etc, and I've used MAMP and other stuff. The problem now is that, I'm trying to use Laravel's Valet. And when I try to access mysite.dev , it opens another website I may have created in the past, which is just an  with the "it works!" sentence. I tried rebooting, shutting down mysql, trying other ports...nothing. Help?

Comment: check your apache virtual host configuration, httpd-vhost.conf file

Comment: where do i see that's running? i just restarted apache and same error. I get a "it works!". I dunno which php or node project is running..

Comment: Mamp is not running, I rebooted my pc, i stopped all services with brew, I still get than index.html from somewhere..

Comment: stop Django web server and start Mamp apache server, seems you have conflict with two web server.

Comment: There's nothing running atm, I even shutdown my computer...And removed the django project's folder...

Comment: ok, i ran sudo apachectl stop and it didnt loaded the mysterious index.html, when i started again it ran again. So it's some apache conflict...how do i know where's the file being loaded?

Comment: Can you check list of running services on your Mac after shutdown. run the command $ ps aux

Comment: How can i edit my apache conf? to see where's the folder he is running that index.html ..

Comment: ok, i inspected further and it seems it has react js there, so it must have been some react app or react-native app, or some xcode stuff

Comment: Can you share `apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file? Did you check it maybe you did a routing for your old project.

Comment: I stopped apache, re installed laravel valet, and now it worked. The routing must have been made by the app or other xcode stuff  tested with...thank you:)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm happy to solve. :)